# httpd linux security and user root

Tags: httpd

On my httpd.conf I use port 8089 and user group apache

I have also changed 443 port https to 4444

but I see a process belong to root,for security reason I want

only apache user process..

```
ps said

root      9675     1  0 19:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache    9769  9675  0 19:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache    9770  9675  0 19:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache    9771  9675  0 19:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent httpd process *must* run as root since it *needs* to be able to do things that only root can do. This process *does not* communicate over the network and should not be considered a security liability.